# Procurar palavras MEMO!

Tags: delphi

Tenho um COMPONENTE MEMO e dentro dele existem várias frases em cada linha.

Preciso procurar palavras desse MEMO, exemplo: "BOLINHA". Até ai tudo bem. O Problema é, depois que ele encontrar a palavra, eu preciso que ele SALVE a LINHA TODA que encontrou a palavra.

Exemplo:

**"TENHO UMA BOLINHA DE GUDE".**

Ele procura a palavra BOLINHA nessa frase, se ele encontrar, ele salva essa FRASE toda em outro MEMO. Apenas isso, podem me ajudar ?

Answer (score 2):

Para isto você devera percorrer o `TMemo` linha a linha e testando se existe a ocorrência da palavra.

Penso em algo como:

```
  for i := 0 to Pred(Memo1.Lines.Count) do
  begin
    if (Memo1.Lines.Strings[i].Contains('BOLINHA') = True) then
      ShowMessage(Memo1.Lines.Strings[i]); //Faça o que quiser com essa linha
  end;
```

No geral é isto, o `Memo1.Lines.Strings[i]` é a linha onde a "Primeira" ocorrência da palavra foi encontrada!